# Attempt at exporting fullcalendar table to Excel format

Tags: jquery, html-table, fullcalendar, export-to-excel

I have been looking around the web and I haven't seen any specific answer to this question: "Can I export my Fullcalendar table into Excel format?".

Some people said that I can maybe fetch my FullCalendar calendar table using Jquery and then use a Jquery plugin to export from html table -> Excel format.

So I have tried to fetch the table using the inspect tool with Chrome:

[image]

However there aren't any id for me to fetch so I can't really "grab" the table object this way it seems. Previously I've used the `.getElementsbyClassName` to get the custom buttons of FullCalendar (after finding the class names using the inspect tool) in order to customize them in the code. However I have several of 'table' objects in code so can't use that (I think?). Are there any other ways to get the Fullcalendar calendar table? Or a even better question, how do I go about exporting Fullcalendar to Excel format (if even possible)? I'm  new at html, Javascript and jQuery.

Comment: Please include your code in a `code` section and not as an image. This would improve your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: If the events are saved in a database just query for them and then save all the results as a CSV. There should be no need to use jQuery to build an excel file.

Comment: save the **events** to Excel, not the calendar table. The calendar is just a way of displaying the events. Excel is terrible at displaying this sort of thing, it's not designed for this kind of presentation, and the HTML structure of the FullCalendar widget is, as you've noticed, a lot more complicated than just a some rows and columns. Excel is meant for data processing, so the thing you should be exporting is the event data, which you can then analyse using Excel's tools. in FullCalendar, the events are a feed of javascript/JSON objects in a consistent format.

Comment: If your Calendar is shown as rows in your table (cannot tell by your post) consider wrapping it in Data Tables. That free grid control has Export to Excel. https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: the way i did this was to ajax to the database, fetch all the events for the given weekly timeframe and build an excel file from scratch using PHPexcel in a seperate php script. this worked out :)